# Compare two columns for matches and pull the adjacent value for each match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to compare the values from two columns on two different sheets (Column G on Sheet A and Column J on Sheet B).  For each match, I want the script to copy the value from Column N of Sheet A to Column K of Sheet B.

I've spent quite a few days trying to figure it out and can't seem to get it right.  Here is some of the code that I've tried -

```
function CopyTCEmailImportV6() {
// gets spreadsheet A and the range of data
var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetA = ssA.getSheetByName('(Test) E-mail List');
var dataA = sheetA.getRange('G:N').getValues();

// gets spreadsheet B and the range of data
var sheetB = ssA.getSheetByName('Ticket Counts (Master)');
var dataB = sheetB.getRange('J:K').getValues();

// loops through column A of spreadsheet A & B and compares
for(var i = 0; i < sheetA.getLastRow(); i++){
  if (dataA[i][0] === dataB[i][0]){
values.push([dataA[i][7]]);
} else {
values.push([""]);
}
}
sheetB.getRange(1, 11, values.length, 
values[0].length).setValues(values);
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[Sheet A - I'd like match the value in Column G with sheet B, and if there's a match copy the corresponding value in Column N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAT5i.png)

[The Column G values from Sheet A should be matched to the Column J values of Sheet B and if there's a match paste the copied values onto the same row in column K.  In this case, "25" should be copied into cell K11.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDIM4.png)

Here's the finished code in case it can help someone out down the line -

```
function CopyTCEmailImportV6() {
  // gets spreadsheet A and the range of data
  var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetA = ssA.getSheetByName('(Test) E-mail List');
  var dataAa = sheetA.getRange('G2:N' + sheetA.getLastRow()).getValues(); // Modified
var dataA = dataAa.reduce(function(ar, n) {
  if (n[7]) ar.push(n)
  return ar;
}, []);

  // gets spreadsheet B and the range of data
  var sheetB = ssA.getSheetByName('Ticket Counts (Master)');
  var dataB = sheetB.getRange('J2:K' + sheetB.getLastRow()).getValues(); // Modified

  // Below script was also added.
  var obj = dataA.reduce(function(o, e) {
    o[e[0]] = e[7];
    return o;
  }, {})
  var values = dataB.map(function(e, i) {return e[0] in obj ? [obj[e[0]]] : [e[1]]});
  sheetB.getRange(2, 11, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to compare the values of the column "G" on the sheet A `(Test) E-mail List` and column "J" on the sheet B `Ticket Counts (Master)`.

  - The row numbers that you want to compare are the same between the column "G" on the sheet A and the column "J" on the sheet B.
- When the values of the column "G" on the sheet A and column "J" on the sheet B are the same, you want to copy from the values of column "N" on the sheet A to the column "K" on the sheet B.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Please modify from `for (var i = 0; i > sheetA.getLastRow(); i++) {` to `for (var i = 0; i < sheetA.getLastRow(); i++) {`.

  - In this case, the for loop doesn't work.
- Please modify from `if (dataA[1][i] === dataB[1][i]){` to `if (dataA[i][0] == dataB[i][0]) {`.

  - For example, in your case, the value of the cell "G1" and "G2" can be retrieved by `dataA[0][0]` and `dataA[1][0]`, respectively.
- When the array for putting to Spreadsheet is created and put the array using `setValues()`, the process cost can be reduced than that of the method that `setValue()` is used in the for loop.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
for(var i = 0; i > sheetA.getLastRow(); i++){
  if (dataA[1][i] === dataB[1][i]){
  var value = sheetA.getRange(i+1, 8).getValue();
  array is 0
  sheetB.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(value);
} // end if;
}; // end i
};
```

To:

```
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sheetA.getLastRow(); i++) {
  if (dataA[i][0] == dataB[i][0]) {
    values.push([dataA[i][7]]);
  } else {
    values.push([""]);
  }
}
sheetB.getRange(1, 11, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

or

```
var values = dataA.map(function(e, i) {return e[0] === dataB[i][0] ? [dataA[i][7]] : [""]});
sheetB.getRange(1, 11, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### References:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)
- [Benchmark: Loop for Array Processing using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/848aeafaac1ec676900bb78e3ce220b6)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

From your shared images, I could know that the values of the column "G" on the sheet A are randomly arranged. And also, it seems that each value of the column "G" is only one in the column "G". By this, I modified above script.

#### Modified script:

```
function CopyTCEmailImportV6() {
  // gets spreadsheet A and the range of data
  var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetA = ssA.getSheetByName('(Test) E-mail List');
  var dataA = sheetA.getRange('G2:N' + sheetA.getLastRow()).getValues(); // Modified

  // gets spreadsheet B and the range of data
  var sheetB = ssA.getSheetByName('Ticket Counts (Master)');
  var dataB = sheetB.getRange('J2:K' + sheetB.getLastRow()).getValues(); // Modified

  // Below script was also added.
  var obj = dataA.reduce(function(o, e) {
    o[e[0]] = e[7];
    return o;
  }, {})
  var values = dataB.map(function(e, i) {return e[0] in obj ? [obj[e[0]]] : [""]});
  sheetB.getRange(2, 11, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
};
```

Comment: Thanks - this was a lot of help!  I'm now receiving the error "Cannot read property "0" from undefined", which I'm guessing is because there are undefined / blank cells within the data I'm pulling.  I updated my question to include an example of sheet A and sheet B to give you a better idea of what I am looking to do.

Comment: @Joey Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer by imaging your current situation. So could you please confirm it? If that didn't resolve your issue, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue by including your current script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I replaced [""] with [e[1]] so that I can keep any values on Sheet A in place that didn't have a match.  I do have one last question - currently, if there is a null value on Sheet B in Column N, it overwrites that null value in it's matched cell on Sheet A.  Is there a way to edit the script so that it skips null values in Column N on Sheet B and doesn't overwrite them on Sheet A?  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Done - and I was able to solve that last part to my question.  I added the finished script.  Can't thank you enough!

Comment: @Joey Thank you for replying and additional information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop seems to be bad,

```
for(var i = 0; i > sheetA.getLastRow(); i++){
```

The > should be a <